# Why doesn't LinkedList(T) implement the IList(T) interface?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, the LinkedList(T) class does not implement the IList(T) interface.  However, the List(T) class does implement IList(T).  Why is there this discrepancy?  Functionally, they are both lists, so this design choice seems odd.  It now becomes difficult to switch implementations from List(T) to LinkedList(T).

Comment: `LinkedList<T>` offer faster insertion and remove operations compared to `List<T>`, at the same time it doesnt offer index operations. It is one trade off  `LinkedList<T>` makes to get insertion and remove faster. The same holds for `List<T>` in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`IList<T>` interface contains an indexer, the indexer is not a functionality you expect on a `LinkedList`.

`List<T>` can assure access to items in *O(1)*, `LinkedList` by definition of it's it structure can't provide access to items in *O(1)*.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your answers.  I overlooked that the definition of an IList is "Represents a collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index."  It doesn't match up with my idea of a list, but hey, it's their language, they can choose the definitions.

Many people have claimed that linked lists cannot support indexing, however the Java language's linked list does indeed have indexes (their documentation makes no claim on it's time-efficiency).

Comment: I ran into this problem once, and ended up making my own IndexedLinkedList class (yeah, it sounds stupid, but was the best option).  It's good to keep track of the differences.

Comment: Note that [ensuring the access of an item in the list in O(1) time is a promise that the *implementation* (`List<T>`) makes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx), [*not* a requirement of the *contract* (`IList<T>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10.aspx).  Your answer is wrong as providing indexed access *can* be accomplished by traversing the linked list.  Of course, doing this will not be as efficient for the general case, taking O(N) time.

Comment: An indexer is not supposed to be necessarily O(1), true, the faster the better and "usually" an indexer is expected to return a value pretty quickly but nothing prevents you to have an indexer with O(n) time...

Answer (score 12):

See the definition of a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), and you will understand.

Main issue, LinkedLists can contain circular references, and thus does not have an index.

> Linked lists are among the simplest
>   and most common data structures; they
>   provide an easy implementation for
>   several important abstract data
>   structures, including stacks, queues,
>   associative arrays, and symbolic
>   expressions.
>
> The principal benefit of a linked list
>   over a conventional array is that the
>   order of the linked items may be
>   different from the order that the data
>   items are stored in memory or on disk.
>   For that reason, linked lists allow
>   insertion and removal of nodes at any
>   point in the list, with a constant
>   number of operations.
>
> On the other hand, linked lists by
>   themselves do not allow random access
>   to the data, or any form of efficient
>   indexing. Thus, many basic operations
>   — such as obtaining the last node of
>   the list, or finding a node that
>   contains a given datum, or locating
>   the place where a new node should be
>   inserted — may require scanning most
>   of the list elements.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that they're the simplest *or* most common data structures. They're a pain in the ass to implement on your own, and have all kinds of issues you have to account for. And I barely ever see them implemented. Stacks are frequently used and very easy to implement on the other hand.

Comment: But that doesn't preclude accessing by index. If you define the indexer such that each successive "hop" in the list decrements the index, then you'd have an indexer. A very inefficient indexer, but an indexer. Hence, I think indexers aren't implemented on a linked list to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot, much like they're not supported directly for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Well the idea is pretty simple, isn't it? Let each node link to its neightbor, and you have yourself a list :).  About most common I agree: I never use LinkedLists!

Comment: @Kent: Building your own index that way would also be pretty useless with a circular reference. ;)

Comment: The LinkedList class can prevent you from creating circular references.  If you don't have access to the list's nodes, then you cannot do anything the LinkedList does not allow.

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa: A stack is often implemented using a LinkedList with the push and pop methods implemented using FILO.

Comment: @Arcturus: What if I wanted a cyclic data structure where all I had to do was increment the index, and it would automatically wrap around to get me the next item? That would be useful. The point is the indexer could work and have well-defined behavior. What it wouldn't have is acceptable performance.

Comment: @Wix: and because all you have for accessors are push and pop, the the implementation becomes far easier in a stack as you don't have to account for all the edge cases involved in the rest of the functionality a traditional linked list provides.

Comment: @Kent: That would be true. But if you would not expect it, it would probably be hard to detect, with terrible performance as well ;)

Comment: @Arcturus: that's the point :) If the performance of indexing on a linked list was guaranteed *O(1)*, I think it would certainly be provided - even for the circular case.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedList is actually a widely-known list data structure which has following operation complexity:

```
Insertion: O(N)

Removal: O(1)

Indexing: O(N)
```

Whereas List is a continuos array, which has following algorithm complexity:

```
Insertion*: O(1)

Removal*: O(N)

Indexing: O(1)
```

They do not provide the common interface, cause it will misguide users of the interface and make programs efficiency unpredictable.
For more information check out books on algorithms and data structures.

Comment: yes, @Jason is right, insertion is O(N) - indeed it's amortised O(N). Appending is amortised O(1). Interestingly enough insertion-at-index is O(N) for a linked list but amortised O(N) for List.

Comment: I start wondering that "same interface" means same function AND same computation complexity?

Comment: Thanks, fixed insertion complexity.

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of guarantee given by an interface, 1 programmatic and 2 conceptual.

The programmatic guarantee is that you can call a method or property that exists. .NET enforces this guarantee.

The first conceptual guarantee is that it will work. This is often broken (NotImplementedException and NotSupportedException exist precisely to break this) but there should be a good reason for doing this. Still, it's more a promise than a guarantee.

The second conceptual guarantee is also more a promise than a guarantee, which is that the method or property will work much like other cases.

People are used to getting on an IList's indexer working in reasonably fast - O(1) or at worse about O(log n) - and breaking that conceptual promise will lead to people using your object badly.

There's no concrete rule here. You certainly can implement IList as a linked list, and suffer the O(n) indexed get. You can also implement a linked list in such a way that it doesn't keep a record of its count (as that supplied by the framework does) and have an O(n) Count property. But then people are more likely to use it badly.

Part of component design is not just making sure things work and work well, but guiding their use. A linked list that implements IList would fail at the latter point, and hence one could make a strong argument that it would not be as good a design as that offered.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply.  I could talk design all day.  I made a comparison to Java earlier and mentioned that Java linked lists support indexes.  It seems the key distinction is that the indexer in .NET is a property and properties, in general, are not expected to do long computations.  Java doesn't have properties nor does it obey their conventions, so their linked list indexer probably runs in O(n).  Too bad...it would be nice to switch my list implementation based on which I thought was more efficient for the job; easier to do if they share the IList interface.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you wrapping a linked-list in something that supports IList, though I would disagree because I agree with the reasoning behind it not supporting it by default. Likewise, if LinkedList really is more efficient for a job, it's likely a job that is best done without use of IList.

Answer (score 2):

This caught me by surprise as well.. Traditionally, a list is just something where you can depend on the order of the elements, and a linked list obeys this, and it should implement IList rather than ICollection (a collection does not say anything about the order of its elements).

Not implementing IList because some operations have poorer complexity than what some people would expect, is wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedList is not a List. Lists are singular dimensional collections of objects. A LinkedList is a node collection, more closely aligned with a Dictionary. Its needs are not similar to a regular List but more specialized to allow for the node traversal and organization behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Historical quirk: in .NET 1.1 an ArrayList was the class that acts like a dynamic length array.

In .NET 2+ still, List internally organizes as an array. This means that IList expects Array semantics, really.

**In .NET, Lists are *like arrays*, not lists....** (boing)

True linked lists have constant time insertion, deletion, but slow enumeration and slower random access.

Arrays have quick enumeration and random access, but have costly insertion / deletion (O(n) and reallocation can quicly lead to completely different behaviour)

Answer (score -1):

Because accessing a linked list by index is not O(1).

Answer (score -1):

A linked list is not a data structure that is designed to be accessed by index, however, `IList<T>` provides index access capabilities.

So, as you can't access items in a linked list by index, you can't provide methods that try to do that.

Answer (score -1):

A "List" is data structure terms is *not* a linked list; it's actually an array -- List item are directly accessible, using the indexer, which is not available (not practical) in a linked list.

Answer (score -1):

Update: After posting my initial response to the question, and getting feedback from the comments, I have found that my answer was wrong, so I updated it the address the flaws in my answer.

The IList interface adds four operations to the ICollection interface which are all applicable if the elements could be accessible by an index number.
The LinkedList is an ordered data structure, so its elements could be accessible using an indexer although it is too time consuming while it is O(n) operation. Although it is an implementation concern, but when designing interfaces we shall bear the performance in mind.

Wrong Reasoning 1:

> If we are removing an interface from a class because its execution
> time is high, then LinkedList shall not implement the IEnumerable
> interface, because it provides the ElementAt operation (extension
> method), which by same reasoning, shall not be provided.

Correction:

> Extension methods are not necessarily methods that shall exist on the
> concreate class itself, but they are the methods that shall not exist
> on the class itself because they pollute the interface or they are not
> acceptable by performance reasons.

Wrong Reasoning 2:

> Also when we are setting the class contracts, we are focusing on the
> available operations that data structure can provide. LinkedList is an
> Ordered collection of elements, so it can be accessed using an index
> number.

Correction:

> We are not designing interfaces by all available operations. We are
> designing interfaces based on logically suitable operations. Using
> indexers on linked list is not a logically suitable operation, hence
> we shall not allow the user to use indexers on linked list.

Final Wrong Reasoning:

> So in conclusion this is a flaw.

Correction:

> So In conclusion linked list shall not implement the accessing via indexers and by same reasoning implementing the IList interface.

Comment: “So in conclusion this is a flaw.” — Absolutely not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph why not? which part of reasoning was wrong?

Comment: Your understanding of how interface are defined is is flawed. Interfaces are defined for *reasonable* sets of operations, not for *comprehensive* sets of operations. An access by index on a linked list, in most circumstances, is not a reasonable operation so a linked list doesn’t implement it. This is pretty much a  universal convention of good interface design. Now, *extension methods* go further than that, and (occasionally) intentionally define methods that go beyond what reasonable interfaces define, for various reasons.

Comment: In sum, just because an extension method exists does not imply that a type should itself implement that method. — In fact, in general *the opposite* is true, and extension methods naturally provide methods that should *not* be implemented on the type itself.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right, thanks. I will update the answer to address my wrong reasoning parts.